# Does "value-maker" here imply "artist"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "the value-maker" in the following imply "the artist"?

> Much like a work of science, a work of art represents a simulacrum of pleasure – it is foregrounded by the values relative to **the value-maker**, attests to multiple layers of possible meaning, is inevitable only in that it privileges the mores of a particular culture at a particular time in history and, within its shifting temporary context, it is ripe for continual reinterpretation
>   and validation.

Comment: I'm assuming the numbered section is your question. Is the rest a quote?

Answer (score 3):

This paragraph is bullshit of the highest order. I am tempted to say that the whole piece is utterly meaningless. It is certainly worthless.

However, as far as I can tell, the "value-maker" is the *observer* of the work of science or art.

When we observe something that has been constructed by another, we automatically evaluate it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

There's an idiom for this:

> [Beauty is in the eye of the beholder](http://www.idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beauty+is+in+the+eye+of+the+beholder)

The quoted individual has used a lot of [purple prose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) to make their point sound more sophisticated, but what they're actually saying is that the 'value-maker' is the person *observing* the art.